# Sharepoint list view issue, list is shown in the whole page and not in the webpart

Tags: sharepoint

There is a sharepoint list created with the limit set to 30 but yesterday i faced an issue wherein the 30 items are filling up on the whole page and not in the webpart of the list. Any help here is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When setting Item Limit to 30, it will show a paging in the footer of the list view web part:
[image]

[image]

What is your meaning filling up on the whole page ? Did the list view page have any custom CSS or script ?